# Go - How to Update a Map that is a Struct Field?

Tags: go

I have tried the following to update an empty map declared as a struct field:

```
package main

type MyStruct struct {
    scoreboard map[string]int
}

func main() {
    mystruct := NewMyStruct()
    mystruct.SubmitWord('test')
}

func NewMyStruct() MyStruct {
    return MyStruct{}
}

func (mystruct *MyStruct) SubmitWord(word string) int {
    mystruct.scoreboard[word] = len(word)
    return len(word)
}
```

but I get an error with `exit status 2`.

The problematic line being `mystruct.scoreboard[word] = len(word)`

Anything I can find seems to suggest this is ok but I haven't found any other examples where the map is within a struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to allocate the map first

```
package main


type MyStruct struct {
    scoreboard map[string]int
}

func main() {
    mystruct := NewMyStruct()
    mystruct.SubmitWord("test")
}

func NewMyStruct() MyStruct {
    var x MyStruct
    x.scoreboard=make(map[string]int)
    return x
}

func (mystruct *MyStruct) SubmitWord(word string) int {
    mystruct.scoreboard[word] = len(word)
    return len(word)
}
```

playground : https://play.golang.org/p/ipqHJ8TdUfh